# How to JSON-escape input?

Tags: text-processing, sed, text-formatting, json, github

I am trying to come up with a tool what for sending data up to a github gist via the API.  The problem is the github api takes the gist `content` as a single line with all escape sequences written out literally, like such:

```json
{
  "test.txt": {
    "filename": "test.txt",
    "type": "text/plain",
    "language": "Shell",
    "raw_url": "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jessebutryn/5c8b2a95b4b016e2fa33edee294c732b/raw/474f72ad32c843c18e9a61a228a31df6b85a8da1/test.txt",
    "size": 96,
    "truncated": false,
    "content": "#!/bin/sh\n\n# comment\nfunc () {\n\tfor ((i=1;i<10;i++)); do\n\t\t:\n\tdone\n}\n\nprintf '%s\\n' Foo bar baz\n"
  }
}
```

That content is displayed as follows:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

# comment
func () {
    for ((i=1;i<10;i++)); do
        :
    done
}

printf '%s\n' Foo bar baz
```

Which needs to be converted to:

```
#!/bin/sh\n\n# comment\nfunc () {\n\tfor ((i=1;i<10;i++)); do\n\t\t:\n\tdone\n}\n\nprintf '%s\\n' Foo bar baz\n
```

---

Are there any tools that do this in one action?  If not does anyone know how it could be done with `sed` or any of the standard unix tools?

---

Note: Any literal escape sequences in the original text will need to be escaped to prevent github from interpreting them (however this would be a secondary issue that doesn't necessarily need to be solved in this question, but would be a nice to have):

ie:

```
printf '%s\n' Foo bar baz
```

becomes:

```
printf '%s\\n' Foo bar baz
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
jq -R -s '.' < datafile
```

This reads in all of `datafile` as a string, and then has jq just print it out as a JSON string. It will give you a quoted string suitable for substituting into that template directly with the contents of `datafile` in it. The data will be correctly JSON-quoted with only the [RFC 7159 escapes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-7) used, and will be in one big line because JSON doesn't allow string literals to span multiple lines.

---

You could also assemble the whole document in jq with a template JSON file and

```
jq --arg f "$(cat datafile)" '.["test.txt"].content = $f' < template.json
```

Very recent versions of `jq` have a `--rawfile f datafile` option that you can use to load a file into a string instead of the command substitution; you could also swap things around with `-R --slurp --slurpfile t template.json datafile` and `t["test.txt"].content = .`.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks!

Comment: Alas this doesn't just json escape, but also surrounds in quotes.

Answer (score 12):

I had to escape some JSON for inclusion in other JSON, and there's a really simple solution:

```
$ jq @json <<< '{"Hello": "World"}'
"{\"Hello\":\"World\"}"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have an existing JSON document in `file.json` and you just want to insert the content into the correct place, using `jq`,

```bsh
jq --rawfile content test.txt '."test.txt".content |= $content' file.json
```

If the content should be base64-encoded:

```bsh
base64 test.txt | jq --rawfile content /dev/stdin '."test.txt".content |= $content' file.json
```

---

Building the JSON from scratch, using `jo` (approximating the meta data from the output of `stat` and `file`):

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

gist_url='some url'
filename=test.txt

jo -p "$filename"="$( jo \
        filename="$filename" \
        type="$( file -b --mime-type "$filename" )" \
        language="$( file -b "$filename" )" \
        raw_url="$gist_url" \
        size="$( stat -c %s "$filename" )" \
        truncated=false \
        content=@"$filename" )"
```

Adjust the `stat` and `file` utilities according to your Unix (the above uses Linux options).

Output:

```json
{
   "test.txt": {
      "filename": "test.txt",
      "type": "text/x-shellscript",
      "language": "POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable",
      "raw_url": "some url",
      "size": 108,
      "truncated": false,
      "content": "#!/bin/sh\n\n# comment\nfunc () {\n    for ((i=1;i<10;i++)); do\n        :\n    done\n}\n\nprintf '%s\\n' Foo bar baz"
   }
}
```

Use `%"$filename"` in place of `@"$filename"` to get a base64-encoded value for the `content` key:

```json
{
   "test.txt": {
      "filename": "test.txt",
      "type": "text/x-shellscript",
      "language": "POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable",
      "raw_url": "some url",
      "size": 108,
      "truncated": false,
      "content": "IyEvYmluL3NoCgojIGNvbW1lbnQKZnVuYyAoKSB7CiAgICBmb3IgKChpPTE7aTwxMDtpKyspKTsgZG8KICAgICAgICA6CiAgICBkb25lCn0KCnByaW50ZiAnJXNcbicgRm9vIGJhciBiYXoK"
   }
}
```